# How do people make a Level in a game with a list of strings in python

Tags: python, pygame

i would like to know because i am making games in pygame and would like to use this method because it looks neat and tidy.

EXE

```
level = "WWWWWWWW" \
        "WSSSSSSW" \
        "WSSSSSSW" \
        "WSSSSSSW" \
        "WSSSSSSW" \
        "WWWWWWWW"
```

Here the s's are empty space and the w's are blocks

Comment: By reading the letters and generating objects that correspond with them.

Comment: Don't you want to have new lines after each string segement using `\n`?

Comment: @jakekimds - That's not really need since he alreay know that the level is a 8x6 in size.

Comment: It would be easier to use 2D arrays instead of strings here. You can make it almost as neat.

Comment: @jakekimds - can u explain more jakekmids

Comment: Arrays are mutable which means it is easier to change just one element. Also, a single element can be accessed faster. You can also iterate over them easier.

Comment: This website explains 2d arrays well: http://www.dotnetperls.com/2d-list-python

Comment: @jakekimds - thank you so much for your help but if wouldent bother you can you show me an example of making am array of this sort turn into a level?

Comment: Can you specify? Are the w's the walls? Do you nee collisions? How much of the code do you need?, the concept or the full code?

Comment: @jakekimds - Ya the w's are blocks while the s's are empty space and i would like for each box to have collision while i know how to add collisions in pygame i would like to know how to add collision between a character and a block that was added by this method of level creation. And for the code just need an example thats clear so that i can study it

Comment: I'm assuming you're using python 2.7

Answer (score 2):

If you use that method, you will need to define the dimensions of the level - LEVELWIDTH and LEVELHEIGHT, in this case 8 and 6, then you can find the block at x, y with this code:

```
LEVELWIDTH = 8
LEVELHEIGHT = 6

def GetBlock(x, y): 
    return level[x * LEVELWIDTH + y]
```

remembering that the indexes x and y both start at zero and end with the last item at the index length - 1 because of Python's method of indexing.

Here is a different method I have used in situations like this:

```
level = ['WWWWWWWW',
         'WSSSSSSW',
         'WSSSSSSW',
         'WSSSSSSW',
         'WSSSSSSW',
         'WWWWWWWW']
```

with this method all you need to do to find what block is at (x, y) is:

```
level[x][y]
```

but remember if you want to be able to edit the level, you need to create a new string for each row you edit, because you cant assign items to a string.
E.g: To set the block at x, y with the string new:

```
level[y] = level[x][:y] + new + level[x][y+1:]
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings for more information on indexing
the method I have shown is based off of the examples in this book
http://inventwithpython.com/pygame/
and a good example of levels in use in the book is in chapter 9 - Star Pusher